# In actionscript, what's the best way to check if a xml node property exists?

Tags: xml, apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3, properties

If I have some xml like so:

```
<books>
    <book title="this is great" hasCover="true" />
    <book title="this is not so great" />
</books>
```

What's the best (or accepted) way in actionscript to check if the hasCover attribute exists before writing some code against it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just to add some precisions.

If you want to check if the property exists even though it's empty you should definitely use hasOwnProperty :

```
var propertyExists:Boolean = node.hasOwnProperty('@hasCover');
```

Checking the length of the content is somehow dirty and will return false if the value of the attribute is empty. You may even have a run-time error thrown as you will try to access a property(length) on a null object (hasCover) in case the attribute doesn't exist.

If you want to test if the property exists and the value is set you should try both **starting with the hasOwnProperty** so that the value test (eventual run-time error) gets ignored in case the attribute doesn't exist :

```
var propertyExistsAndContainsValue:Boolean = (node.hasOwnProperty('@hasCover') && node.@hasCover.length());
```

Comment: node.@hasCover.length() should check the length of the XMLList returned by node.@hasCover, not the length of the String value of the hasCover attribute. I say "should", because here we bump into the nasty automatic type conversion built in E4X. To check for the length of the attribute value, I would use node.@hasCover[0].length. This makes sure we get the first value in the returned XMLList, then uses the String.length property to check the length of the content.

Answer (score 6):

Ok - I ran across this today and a.) it was used by Ely Greenfield and b.) it's painfully simple so I have to mark it as the answer unless someone can site a reason not to...

```
if("@property" in node){//do something}
```

Comment: Definitely the way to go. Our whole platform (Mockingbird) is built on top of XML documents and this is how I check that attributes (or child elements) exist. I believe it's byte-code-equivalent to hasOwnProperty but looks way more readable (in my opinion).

Answer (score 5):

See [question #149206: "Best way to determine whether a XML attribute exists in Flex"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/149206/best-way-to-determine-whether-a-xml-attribute-exists-in-flex/149316#149316).

I suggested doing `event.result.hasOwnProperty("@attrName")` but [the answer with the most upvotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/149206/best-way-to-determine-whether-a-xml-attribute-exists-in-flex/149794#149794) (at the time of this writing) by Theo suggests this:

```
event.result.attribute("attrName").length() > 0
```